# How to create information link in Spotfire with sub Queries

Tags: spotfire

I am new with Tibco Spotfire, I am trying to create information link which has sub query like below  
 `SELECT column1  from (SELECT column-name FROM table-name)` 
 while creating information link we have to add columns from `database Table` and based on that columns we create Information Link. but in my case, I am selecting column from result. 
I looked into Spotfire documentation but no similar example/scenario are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while searching with Spotfire I got clue how to use nested queries, So I think it will help for other, if any one facing same issue. So just create columns that you want to use in Outer query, and use it. 
here are the steps for it.

```
1) Tools -> information Designer -> Data Source -> Database -> Table
2) Select Colums and Add
3) Create Information Link
4) select recently created Column
5) Add your SQL
6) Load Data
```